# jquery events are not persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code, I see my jquery replacing the click me away text to testing, but it quickly reverts it to the original text. could someone kindly tell what the issue is? Any help is appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#but").click(function(){
            $("p").text("testing");
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

      </form>
    </div>
       <p>Click me away!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When your form is submitted the page is being refreshed. Change button type to button and that should solve your issue. You could also move the button outside the form, or have the submit event return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean it's revert
if you refresh your page, this text revert to your original text.If you want to not submit your page you can set `return false`
please check my fiddle code (http://jsfiddle.net/tommoholmes/cea6dz35/)

Comment: or better yet, don't use `type="submit"` if you don't actually want to submit.

Comment: Please post the fiddle, or a snippet, in the question, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but").on('click', function(e){
            $("p").text("testing");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Better use event.preventDefault() instead of return false. And for last jquery version use on instead of click function.

Link about return false vs. event.preventDefault()

http://blog.nmsdvid.com/when-to-use-return-false-and-when-preventdefault/

http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.on('click', function(){
    $("p").text("testing");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I still see the issue where the text "testing" quickly appears and goes back to the old text.